# 400 bad request, but there is nothing wrong with this page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am using paged lists on my mvc application. I have tons of different pages that do this, but for SOME random reason, this one throws a 400 bad request error. I am almost positive the code is the same.

```
public ViewResult ManageWeapons(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "WeaponName_desc" : "";
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    var weapon = from s in db.Weapons
                 select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        weapon = weapon.Where(s => s.WeaponName.Contains(searchString));
    }
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "WeaponName_desc":
            weapon = weapon.OrderByDescending(s => s.WeaponName);
            break;
        default:  // ascending 
            weapon = weapon.OrderBy(s => s.WeaponName);
            break;
    }
    int pageSize = 25;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(weapon.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

I invoke it as so, to sort a column

```
//This function updates a pagedList using Ajax
function getSorterWeapons(sortOrder, currentFilter) {
    //alert($(this).val());
    console.log("making it!");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("ManageWeapons", "AdminTools")',
        cache: false,
        data: { sortOrder: sortOrder, currentFilter: currentFilter },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error occurred.");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#manageWeaponsBox").html(data);
            console.log("success!");
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I have set breakpoints on the server and it makes it through just fine. Nothing seems to be going wrong, but the client constantly outputs 400 error in console.

I am doing this EXACT same function for other tables in my database and it works fine. This one has me to wits end.

Comment: Have you checked your server for thrown or swallowed exceptions?

Comment: Are you able to use the browser console to debug into the ajax call?  The networks tab often has good info.

Comment: Also, are you sure that is a `GET` and not a `POST`?

Comment: What I don't understand is why the page loads just fine normally, but when I use the ajax call to refresh this table it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This one would have been rather obvious has it been in an `HTML post`. The problem is as simple as that I had an error in the view (from accidently adding a character). The c# function was executing fine and then the code was breaking in the view side, one of the pitfalls of debugging using ajax and mvc.